# AWS ElasticBeanstalk can't find Dockerfile

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have the following directory layout

```
./www/index.php
Dockerfile
apache-config.conf
```

I then zip up the file and upload it onto Elastic Beanstalk, but I get the following error message:

```
[Instance: i-572d1ae8] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json are both missing, abort deployment. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

The log file contains the following message:

```
AppDeployPreHook/01unzip.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Archive:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
     creating: /var/app/current/DI_Test/
    inflating: /var/app/current/DI_Test/.DS_Store  
     creating: /var/app/current/__MACOSX/
     creating: /var/app/current/__MACOSX/DI_Test/
    inflating: /var/app/current/__MACOSX/DI_Test/._.DS_Store  
    inflating: /var/app/current/DI_Test/apache-config.conf  
    inflating: /var/app/current/DI_Test/Dockerfile  
    inflating: /var/app/current/__MACOSX/DI_Test/._Dockerfile  
     creating: /var/app/current/DI_Test/www/
    inflating: /var/app/current/DI_Test/www/.DS_Store  
     creating: /var/app/current/__MACOSX/DI_Test/www/
    inflating: /var/app/current/__MACOSX/DI_Test/www/._.DS_Store  
    inflating: /var/app/current/DI_Test/www/index.php  
[2015-10-29T14:01:33.279Z] INFO  [2865]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] : Starting activity...
[2015-10-29T14:01:33.579Z] INFO  [2865]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json are both missing, abort deployment (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json are both missing, abort deployment (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Why is my dockerfile not being read here? I can build the image and run it just fine without Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 26):

Sharing another possibility:

You were testing eb and you've just added your Dockerfile.

According to the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html)

> If git is installed, EB CLI uses the git archive command to create a
>   .zip file from the contents of the most recent git commit command.

That's saying if your Dockerfile is not committed, it won't be zipped in therefore your instance can't find it.

Comment: This nipped me in the but.  As I was using CLI, I needed to update the image I was using differently than what was it git for Dockerrun.aws.json.  The other piece that is helpful was adding an .ebignore file.  That forced the EB CLI to pick up my non-git changes

Comment: Wow, that's so unexpected! I would imagine that it just straight up zips your current directory.

Answer (score 7):

Compress those stuff within your project folder(go into your project folder and zip everything), instead of zipping your project folder.

Comment: This was probably the most annoying thing. Thank you for pointing this out.
`cd /path/to/project; zip Archive.zip *;`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to include parent directory in zip file. Suppose you want to zip ./www/index.php ,Dockerfile and apache-config.conf then,

```
zip dist.zip Dockerfile ./www/index.php apache-config.conf
```

The upload dist.zip.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deployment.source.html

Answer (score 2):

I've come across this issue as well. It seems a `Dockerrun.aws.json` file is required as well. I believe that is because other files are included in the app. If you had only a `Dockerfile` and nothing else, it wouldn't be required.

Here's the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a **spelling mistake** in `Dockerfile` name i.e DockerFile. Elastic Beanstalk is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Super newbie mistake, but when I had this problem it was because my `Dockerfile` was actually `Dockerfile.txt`. After removing the `.txt` extension and creating a plain file it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The solution is to go to the actual directory that you are trying to zip and then run: `zip name_of_file.zip *`. Then the Dockerfile will get the exact same zip filename "Dockerfile", which is what Elastic Beanstalk is looking for.
If you zip from outside your directory, the Dockerfile's name will be "directory/Dockerfile", and that is what causes Elastic Beanstalk to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem. Using directly json, the Dockerrun files can have the form of `Dockerrun_${DOCKER_TAG}.aws.json`.

**Solution:** In zips, only `Dockerrun.aws.json` is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible problems:

1) When zipping the folder enter the folder and zip from the command line or in finder select each file individually then zip together. 
Example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html

2) Elastic Beanstalk is case sensitive so make sure your file is labeled "Dockerfile" not "dockerfile"

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to upload a zip which contained a singular file Dockerrun.aws.json. But [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html) state:

> If you use only a Dockerfile or only a Dockerrun.aws.json file to deploy your application, you don't need to create a .zip file

So you can simply upload either one or another without zipping it.

Answer (score 0):

To document just another way to get into this - added by mistake Dockerfile in the .ebignore file. I was testing non-docker and docker deploys and worked from the same directory. Dockerfile is not obviously needed with regular deploys but should not be added to .ebignore when doing docker deploys.

Answer (score 0):

I added the `dockerrun.aws.json` and `config.yml` in a folder called `.elasticbeanstalk/` which is in the root folder.